# When the following exponential and factorial congruent equation has a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n,m\geq 3$ be two given integers. Then when the following equation $$m^x\equiv 1+n!\mod (n+1)!$$ has a positive integer solution. If such solution exists, then how can we explicitly find it?
I give some of my idea, first, we have that $$n!\mid m^x-1.$$ From this, we have
$$n\mid m^x-1.$$ For example, if $m=3,n=5$, then we must have $$x=4t,t\in \mathbb{Z}.$$ I can only consider this problem at this step, and do not know how to continue..... I do not know how to use the Wilson theorem on this problem.

Comment: Yes. We only consider the positive integer case.

Comment: I think it may be helpful if we  firstly consider $m=3,n=5$. For this case we have $gcd(3,5)=1$, therefore,  more existed results can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

Let's do some experiments:

$n=2\rightarrow m^x=6k+3$

which gives:

$(m, x)=(3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4),(3, 5) \cdot\cdot$

$n=3\rightarrow m^x= 24k+7$

which gives:

$(m, x)=(7, 3), (31, 3)\cdot\cdot $

$n=4\rightarrow m^x=120k+24$

which gives:

$(m, x)=(5, 4), (25, 3), (25, 4),(5, 6)\cdot\cdot$

$n=5\rightarrow m^x=720k+121$

which gives:

$(m, x)=(161, 2), (101, 2), (259,2)$

$n=6\rightarrow m^x=5040k+721$

which gives:

$(m, x)=(161,2)$

For n=7 and n=8 I could not find any solution , may be by powerful computers one may find some solutions for any n. I do not see any particular condition.

Comment: Many thanks. I am wondering when $n$ is large,  how can we find some solutions.